# Bottom column not aligned. css?

Tags: css

On http://www.devinkbb.nl I want the bottom right column to align with the pictures on the left. For some reason it adds a min-height: 200px;  to the column, so that it sticks out. The pictures have a height of 180px.

I have tried to give the column a class, #ddd. The max height is set to 180px in css but this doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `min-height:180px` for the class `.fusion-column-last .fusion-column-wrapper`, It is working fine in browser.

See the image for reference.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because image wrapped into `<p>` and `<p>` has `margin-bottom: 20px`

[image]

There are 2 things you can do.

**1st Solution:**

Add class in: `<p class="mb0">`

Add new css rule

```
.post-content p.mb0 {
  margin-bottom: 0px
}
```

**2nd Solution:**

Remove `<p>` that wrapped over `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-height:0;` to `.fusion-column-wrapper`

It will look like

```
.fusion-column-last .fusion-column-wrapper{
   min-height:0;
}
```

I have included `.fusion-column-last` to avoid the style getting applied to other divs with class `.fusion-column-wrapper`. If it is still getting overridden, add `!important` after `min-height:0`

Answer (score 0):

1. **Answer:**

`margin-bottom: 20px;` change into `margin-bottom: 10px;`

2. **Answer:**
   First two `<p></p>` tag use `margin-bottom: 20px;` and last tag use `margin-bottom: 0px;`

Use it. It should work.